# how to extract a joomla url

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to overwrite the mod_wrapper and I want to copy the current URL and add that specific section from it to the mod_wrapper src URL.

I tried with following but it doesnt work

my current URL is: mydomain/member-portal?dis_code=ABC123

now I want to extract above URL and get only `?dis_code=ABC123`

my mod_wrapper has following src. but

```
src="<?php echo $url . "?" . JURI::base( true ) . "\n"; ?>"
```

But this doesnt work. But Joomla Documentation has the following.

```
echo 'Joomla base URI is ' . JURI::base() . "\n";
echo 'Joomla base URI (path only) is ' . JURI::base( true ) . "\n";
```

results

```
Joomla base URI is `mywebsite/joomla/`
Joomla base URI (path only) is /joomla
```

Answer (score 1):

The Joomla method to get the url would be at [docs.joomla.org/JURI/current](http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/current)

From there, you can extract what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change JURI::base() by  JUri::base(). This sentence will return exactly your url.

```
echo JUri::base();
```